# How to use DataBinding event in DataList

Tags: asp.net

I am using DataList and want to bind data through databinding event.
When i tried to bind data using ItemdatBound event than its give error and when i am using breakpoint than it was first go to the datBinding event and than source code and when its goes to the source code, its give error that "System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'iParentPageId_PK"
So What I do Now???

Its My Code...

```
protected void dlRight_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        Label lblId = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblId");
        SubPage objEntity = new SubPage()
        {

            ParentPageId = Convert.ToInt32(lblId.Text)

        };
        dlRight.DataSource = objSubBll.GetByParentPageId(objEntity);
        dlRight.DataBind();
    }
}
protected void dlRight_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: Look like you are accessing **iParentPageId_PK** in ASXP page, but **DataSource** doesn't have a column with named **iParentPageId_PK**.

Comment: @Win:- No Sir, Its have...

Comment: Pleas show us the ASPX page.

Comment: @Win:- Its My Table Content...SELECT TOP 1000 [iParentPageId_PK]
      ,[sTitle]
      ,[sContent]
      ,[sUrl]
      ,[sMetaTitle]
      ,[sMetaDescription]
      ,[sMetaKeyword]
      ,[iLocation]
      ,[iShowon]
      ,[bIsActive]
  FROM [dbCMS].[dbo].[tbParentPage]

Comment: <asp:DataList ID="dlRight" runat="server" 
                    onitemdatabound="dlRight_ItemDataBound">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("iParentPageId_PK") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("sTitle") %>' ></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:DataList>

Comment: Do you see `iParentPageId_PK` column in the result if you run `SELECT * FROM tbParentPage`?

Comment: @win- Yes, already checked this..